# Loading profiler failed during CoCreateinstance - error, but I'm not using a profiler

Tags: azure, .net-4.0, profiler

Recently I published to my Azure Staging server (Asp.Net MVC App) and my app wouldn't come up.  I checked the Event logs on the machine, and this was the error:

> .NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.18033 - Loading profiler failed during
>   CoCreateInstance. Profiler CLSID:
>   '{F1260058-1A1F-4738-8BE2-0BF9D3A64219}'. HRESULT: 0x8007007e. Process
>   ID (decimal): 1872. Message ID: [0x2504].

The thing is that I am not using a profiler, everything worked fine yesterday (day old publish) - any ideas what could be causing this, and how I could fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not to say there is not a better fix (I tried all I could find elsewhere, nothing seemed to relate to my specific problem) but here is what I ended up doing. Simply delete your deployment, and re-publish. This must re-set whatever turning on your profiler sets.

[image]

Remember that if this is a non domain dns instance, your address will be changed. Hope this can save someone a few hours.

[Blog Post Here](http://www.naspinski.net/post/2013/06/06/Azure-Error-NET-Runtime-version-403031918033-Loading-profiler-failed-during-CoCreateInstance)